# How to combine multiple date-between searches with CrudRepository of Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

spring-data provides a way to generate SQL search by defining the method name.

The following works fine:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
  Date from, to;
}

//CrudRepository<Book>
findByFromDateBetween(Date departure, Date arrival);
```

But why then does the following not work?

```
findByFromDateBetweenAndToDateBetween(Date departure, Date arrival);
```

To connect two date searches, I have to repeat the date:

```
findByFromDateBetweenAndToDateBetween(Date departure, Date arrival, Date departure, Date arrival);
```

Question: is it possible to reuse the params?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Between` keyword naturally binds two parameters. Thus after binding the from clause, the parameter list is exhausted and we don't know which parameters to use for the second criteria.

A manually defined query should do the trick:

```
interface BookRepository extends Repository<Book, Integer> {

  @Query("select b from Book b " +
         "where b.from between ?1 and ?2 and b.to between ?1 and ?2")
  List<Book> findByDatesBetween(Date departure, Date arrival);
}
```