# How to add restriction to range between two dates on query by example in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have one class with two dates and my search is dynamic, Hibernate provides Query By Example (QBE), but now use QBE of Spring Data. The problem is when created a QBE but the documentation restrict the ExampleMatcher for String types, i need create a ExampleMatcher for search all entities between in this dates.

How implement this using query by example?.

My alternatives for now is:

- Create a hibernate dao and use QBE and criteria of hibernate (Bye JPA :'( )
- Explore this http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/ (really ugly code)

Example properties for class:

```
  private int id;
  private String property1;
  private String property2;
  private Date dateFirst;
  private Date dateSecond;
```

Related :

- http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.usage
- [How to combine multiple date-between searches with CrudRepository of Spring Data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870095/how-to-combine-multiple-date-between-searches-with-crudrepository-of-spring-data)
- [Spring Data JPA: Query by Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626825/spring-data-jpa-query-by-example)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is, you don't. Query by example is considered exactly what its name suggests: you give an example and the query is built on a match of the given fields. That's also documented in the "Limitations" [section of the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.usage) you linked to.

For more advanced use cases and predicate definitions, have a look at the Querydsl support.

Comment: i prefer make a dao and use hibernate criteria for this purpose for now , i need study this case and how to combine with hibernate-search, thanks , great project