# Spring data jpa repository find by multi elements

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `Spring Data JPA` in my project. So in repository, I define a list by following:

```
List<Branch> findByNameContainingAndByTypeContaining(String name, String type)
```

It works in this case, however, in the search form, I got more than 10 search criteria, it means and in search method, it requires more than 10 elements, and properly, field of them has value.

For example:

```
name: abc
type: primary
enabled: true
createdBy: null
modifiedBy: null
and so more
```

for `findBy` method if I send blank, it works but null value. Moreover, so many fields to search. So I'm looking for a better way to search a form like this. In Grails framework, I can create nameQueries for this but not find a better way in `Spring JPA`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [QueryByExample](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) API, for example:

```
Branch branch = new Branch();                          
branch.setName("Foo");
branch.setEnabled(true)                           

ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching();        
Example<Branch> example = Example.of(branch, matcher);
branchRepository.findAll(example)
```

You can choose to include or ignore `null` values, and specify case sensitivity, etc.

More examples are [here in the Spring Data Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.matchers).

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hi, just have a question, now, I have a search form, with fromDate and toDate, and it needs to compare with datetime field in Branch to get data, how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @TranTam Not possible with QueryByExample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41056515/1258079