# Spring JPA - Getting all entities that have any of X date columns between range

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have an Organization entity that extends from AbstractEntity, which is giving it three date columns: createdAt, updatedAt and checkedAt.

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

  @Column(name = "createdAt")
  protected LocalDateTime createdAt;

  @Column(name = "updatedAt")
  protected LocalDateTime updatedAt;

  @Column(name = "checkedAt")
  protected LocalDateTime checkedAt;

  //more stuff
}
```

On the OrganizationRepository I made some query methods for getting any of 'createdAt', 'updatedAt' or 'checkedAt' which are working wonderfully, but I tried making a query method that checks all three columns at the same time and it breaks the build with a couple java.lang.IllegalStateException at PartTreeJpaQuery.java:161 exceptions.

```
@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, String>{

  List<Organization> findByParentOrganizationIsNull();

  Optional<Organization> findByExternalId(String id);

  List<Organization> findByCreatedAtBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end);
  List<Organization> findByUpdatedAtBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end);
  List<Organization> findByCheckedAtBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end);
  // THIS LAST ONE DOESN'T WORK
  List<Organization> findByCreatedAtBetweenOrUpdatedAtBetweenOrCheckedAtBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end);

}
```

How can I make a query that checks that Any of the three columns is between the start and end dates??

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Organization> findByCreatedAtBetweenOrUpdatedAtBetweenOrCheckedAtBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end);
```

or alternatively

```
List<Organization> findByCreatedAtOrUpdatedAtOrCheckedAtBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end);
```

Don't work, as far as I understand now, because the start and end parameters get consumed by each Between, so the next ones don't know what parameters to use. See [How to combine multiple date-between searches with CrudRepository of Spring Data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870095/how-to-combine-multiple-date-between-searches-with-crudrepository-of-spring-data)

The solution was making a regular @Query with the column between OR column between OR column between, that uses both parameters several times.

```
@Query("select o from Organization o " +
        "where o.createdAt between ?1 and ?2 " +
        "or o.updatedAt between ?1 and ?2 " +
        "or o.checkedAt between ?1 and ?2")
List<Organization> findByAnyDateBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end);
```

Comment: Use 3 pair of same start/end in method naming query then it will work

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks not exactly following you, can you write an example method?

Comment: I mean `List<Organization> findByCreatedAtBetweenOrUpdatedAtBetweenOrCheckedAtBetween(LocalDateTime start1, LocalDateTime end1,LocalDateTime start2, LocalDateTime end2,LocalDateTime start3, LocalDateTime end3);`

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks oh yeah, if you add multiple end and start dates that should work! thanks for the alternative